# pgrouting with Navteq data

Tags: pgrouting

I realized that osm-data is not as complete as I need to have it for my work.
I'm considering trying a branch of navteq and later buy the data branch for my region.

Has anyone tried routing with navteq data? Is there an importtool like osm2pgrouting, which would make life very easy!

Where can I download a simple shapefile with a bunch of nodes and ways? All the dev. stuff seams to be very overloaded and in GDF3.0 format.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you write your own script to load the navteq data?

Comment: Navteq data can be imported with ogr2ogr for example.

Comment: I am referring to building the pgrouting graph once the data is already in. I ended building it with a few queries I wrote (been running for a day still), but I was wondering if you used something out of the box or not.

Comment: I had to put priorities on other things unfortunatly - but I'm keen to see your solution as I have to do it very soon!

Answer (score 2):

You can join the [Navteq Developer Network](http://www.nn4d.com) and receive a full featured sample data set for a select number of regions.

It does take a little time, and you need to register/verify your profile, including name, organisation (can be an individual), contact information, though you will get a full featured data set.  It comes in Shapefile, Mapinfo Tab and GDF 3.0.

I am working with the data set now, and have only come across a couple of white papers detailing how to load the GDF format into an Oracle and MSSQL Server database.

The Navteq spatial assets are extensive.

Comment: thanks. Did that already, just didn't download the data as I thought it's just GDF3.0 - will download it now!